# Selenium webdriver screenshot in Python has the wrong resolution

Tags: python, selenium

I´m taking screenshots using the selenium and Firefox geckodriver on Windows 10 with

```
delay = 5
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\A0048436\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe")
browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
browser.get('file://' + html_file)
time.sleep(delay)
browser.save_screenshot(html_file + '.png')
browser.quit()
```

so I expected that the image resolution would be the window size, but it´s not - it´s lower. How can I set the screenshot resolution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `set_window_size` set the size of the window which includes the borders, menu bars and tabs.

To set the size of the viewport, you first need to compute the difference between the outer window and the inner window. Then add this difference to the desired resolution:

```
dx, dy = browser.execute_script("var w=window; return [w.outerWidth - w.innerWidth, w.outerHeight - w.innerHeight];")
browser.set_window_size(1920 + dx, 1080 + dy)
```

Comment: It´s almost right - there a tiny size difference, but it´s good enough. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. After 10 hours of trying different things, this finally solved it for me using capybara and ruby. The code was a bit different, but the same thing applies. The strange thing - 2 years ago I programmed a similar thing and it worked out of the box.